# Heroku scheduler with EC2 SauceConnect SSH Tunnel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ssh, capybara, saucelabs

I have a bit of a unique situation with our testing setup. Basically what I would like to do is have Heroku run our integration tests with Sauce Connect at scheduled intervals. Sauce Connect requires an SSH tunnel to be opened up before running the tests, so I'm trying to have the SSH tunnel run on an Amazon EC2 instance. I've been testing it locally and my script can successfully connect to EC2, start the SSH tunnel remotely, then begin running the tests on my local machine. However, when I log into Sauce Labs and check the video of the browser tests being performed, every single one is returning a 404 connection refused. When I check 'netstat -an' on the EC2 instance I can see that the SSH connection to Sauce Labs is being successfully established, but for some reason it can't seem to run the tests successfully using the remote SSH tunnel. Has anyone run into this issue, or perhaps have some insight as to why this would be giving the errors it's giving? Thanks!

Comment: Do you intend to host your tests (& test environment) on EC2 itself?  IE were you just using your local machine as a test runner to make sure your setup was working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this addresses your particular problem, but here's a detailed recipe for setting up a tunnel on Heroku: [SSH tunneling from Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575582/ssh-tunneling-from-heroku/27361295#27361295) .

The biggest challenge I found in setting up a tunnel was getting things to a state where ssh didn't prompt for user input.